# Emacs dired mode, trying to achieve "ssh -F ~/xyzdir/my_custom_config

Tags: emacs, ssh, vagrant, tramp

I want to use a ssh config file that is *not* in

```
~/.ssh/config.
```

When I use the command line

```
sh -F my_ssh_config
```

it works.

Now I want to do the same from Emacs dired (tramp).

Whatever I try it hangs on connecting to my vagrant `VM` .

What I am trying to do :

- I have multiple vagrant project directories, each with its own ssh
  private key, some of these are discarded/temporary
- I like to
  browse my VM folders using Emacs dired
- I don't want to use my
  ~/.ssh/config file - it will get cluttered with these ssh connections

Attempted tweak (got "process died" from Tramp)

```
ELISP> ( tramp-get-completion-function "ssh")

((tramp-parse-connection-properties "ssh")
 (tramp-parse-shosts "~/.ssh/known_hosts")
 (tramp-parse-sconfig "/path/to/my_ssh_config_file"))
```

Also "my_ssh_config_file" functions correctly when used in the shell command "ssh -f my_ssh_config_file" - and gets into my vagrant box.

Comment: I would probably start by taking a look at the functions that begin with `tramp-parse-` in `tramp.el` and see if that gives you any ideas.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You should probably describe which aspect of the SSH connection you wish to override instead; Tramp has a lot of options for that.

Answer (score 0):

Tramp does not support alternative config files. Connection arguments are defined in `tramp-methods`. Check this variable, and double an entry (for example the `"ssh"` entry) to `"myssh"` with the arguments you need. However, be careful, because Tramp has several assumptions on the arguments.

Comment: I kind of suspect this.. I will take a look into tramp.el .  I have already tried to tweak as described in my note above in the question description. thanks

Comment: What you have tweaked above was the autoexpand feature for host names. For connection parameters, you must tweak `tramp-methods`. Don't hesitate to ask, when you are in doubt.